# How does one take functions using .bind(param, param), used internally in a function, and convert this to React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vis.js-network

So I have this vanilla JS code that I'm trying to convert to React but I'm struggling with how to pass the parameters from the original editNode function down to the saveNodeData function.

The problem is that when the buttons are clicked callback is not a function because it is not being pass the original parameters from editNode.

Vanilla:

```
function editNode(data,callback) {

/more irrelevant code/
    document.getElementById("node-saveButton").onclick = saveNodeData.bind(this, data, callback);
    document.getElementById("node-cancelButton").onclick = cancelNodeEdit.bind(this, callback);
/more irrelevant code/
}
```

I already have bound the two functions for cancelNodeEdit and saveNodeData to two buttons as seen here:

```
<Button variant="contained" onClick={cancelNodeEdit}>Cancel</Button>
<Button variant="contained" onClick={saveNodeData}>Save</Button>
```

and here are the two functions I'm using:

```
function saveNodeData(data, callback) {
        data.label = nodeLabel;
        data.name = nodeName;
        data.description = nodeDescription;
        data.nodeType = nodeType;
        data.organization = organization;

        setNodeEditor(false);
        callback(data);
    }

const cancelNodeEdit = (callback) => {
        setNodeEditor(false);
        callback(null);
    };
```

I'd like to point out that this is for vis.js which uses callbacks to return the data to the manipulation object. https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/manipulation.html#

***Edit:***
This codepen actually demonstrates exactly what we currently have in the Vanilla version and I'm trying to figure out the conversion to React: https://codepen.io/NomuraS/pen/jZeVBg

Here's my Gist of the current code I have: https://gist.github.com/natetewelde/7545cf540229296228b8aa44c1de50c2

Comment: Just not any different? `.bind()` is still in ES6 and is commonly used in React.

Comment: Notice that in React you should avoid mutating the `data` that was passed into your component, like `saveNodeData` does. But that has nothing to do with `.bind()`.

Comment: Do I still need to use ‘this’ inside the bind function call?

Comment: Given that the function which you are binding do not use `this` themselves (particularly `cancelNodeEdit` which is an arrow function), you can bind them to anything you like. Using `this` works, but I'd recommend `null` to make it explicit.

Comment: I think I’ve tried this in the 3 million different iterations I’ve tried to code this but for some reason the buttons didn’t do anything. How do I take these bound functions and use them with an onClick? I’ve been struggling with this for like a week now to no avail. If you’re available via discord that would be super appreciated

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the whole React component, please?

Comment: The functions I am calling are part of a context file I'm using to pass propsbetween different components. If you'd like I can create some gists of the different files? https://gist.github.com/natetewelde/7545cf540229296228b8aa44c1de50c2

Comment: Graph.js is the context file, node.js is the original JS, and node editor is the  dialog im using to edit nodes dynamically

Comment: Also regarding your second comment about data mutation, what would be the right way to go about that?